# Recording video in C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I have to do the following: record video from a camera using C#. The camera I use produces video frames (the frame rate is not fixed) and I have to somehow put all the frames together and create a video file. Also I need to use different codecs, such as [AVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) or [MPEG-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4) (these codecs are required, others are optional).

The main problem I faced was how to create a video in which the frame rate is not fixed. I have a stream of frames. For example, I can receive the first frame after 1 ms, then after 20 ms, then 36 ms and so on. If I create video with 25 frames/second the result will be wrong because it means that frames are added after 40 ms.

I tried to use Aforge.Video library. It has [a method](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/84a560df-bfd5-e0d6-2812-f810b56a254d.htm) which adds a frame according to a timespan. But this method has problems with setting the bitrate. The bitrate value I pass to the method is simply ignored (*[About an FFmpeg bitrate and framerate issue](http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2665)*).

Is there some C# library which I can use to do video recording? I have to support AVI and MPEG-4, and also the possibility to set the bitrate and last but not least - record video with a variable framerate.

I can't connect to the camera directly. All I have is a stream of frames and I need to convert this stream to video at run time.

A library I'm looking for should satisfy the following properties. It has to contain a method (or some way how to do the same) to add the next frame with a timestamp, just like in Aforge.Video.FFMPEG:

```
public void WriteVideoFrame(Bitmap frame, TimeSpan timestamp)
```

And it should be possible to choose different codecs (at least AVI and MPEG-4) and also to set bitrate.
Are there some alternatives to Aforge.Video.FFMPEG? Because Aforge doesn't work properly. The bitrate value is ignored, and also some codecs are not supported ([MPEG-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-2) for example).

About the codec license. If I use an open source library, should I worry about the codec license?

Answer (score 2):

- AVI and MPEG-4 are not codecs, but container formats
- APIs and libraries are all well known. The problem here is that specific formats and codecs have their own limitations, e.g., an AVI file has to have a fixed frame rate for video (with a workaround that you might have a high FPS file with skipped frames)

The finest control API you typically use from C# code for video recording is DirectShow through [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library. You choose formats and codecs, AVI multiplexer is available as a stock component, and there are third-party replacements. For MPEG-4 (`.MP4`), you need a third-party component, e.g., [this](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/). The video compression component is typically subject to a third-party filter choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I still have some questions:
1) Is it possible to record video in DirectShow simply adding new frames? I mean without establishing a connection to camera.
2) Where I can ask about libraries similar to Aforge.Video? I've googled it but found nothing suitable.
3) I don't want to use different libraries for different formats. I thought about the following: at first, record a video in some format, then using ffmpeg for example convert it to desired format. What do you think about it?

Comment: `1` - yes; the method is popular but not so straightforward because a custom built C++ filter/DLL is needed to connect your C# source of frames and standard DirectShow pipeline; `2` library forum or here if the question is specific and well-formed (typically with source code snippet); `3` - additional conversion step does not make much sense to me but it's up to you to decide, with a video encoding task you typically have to deal with third party libraries anyway, you just need to select the right ones.

Comment: 1 - Could you give me some information or a link describing how to do that, please?

Comment: You need to build a DirectShow pipeline, starting from source of data and terminating by a so called renderer filter. Something injects data (frames) and then they are terminated by recording into file. The pipeline is about this: Your Custom Source -> Video Compression -> Multiplexer -> File Writer. Compression and Multiplexing are format specific and are either standard or third party components. File Writer is a standard component. Custom Source needs to be yours, here is [a lead into this task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934343/directshow-push-source-filter-in-c).

Comment: Thank you! But it seems to me too complicated for such an easy task - just convert stream of frames to video. One more question - I don't quite understand how DirectShow works with a camera. I suppose the driver should be certified or something, am I right? Because I have a driver to my camera and it contains specific functions - to set various options, to get stream of frames, to get single picture.   Is it possible to connect this camera with DirectShow?

Comment: Presumably what you think of as a "driver" to the camera, is not really a driver and is a sort of SDK instead. Perhaps it is possible to wrap it up into normal DirectShow source.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for a way to combine video fragments -- some call it 'video stitching'. Another option for you is to search for video encoding services, may be easier than reinventing the wheel -- here's an example of a service that has an API you can use in c#: http://api.encoding.com/

Comment: @ScottProkopetz and is there a library which can do the same?

Comment: @RomanR. perhaps it's possible, but still it seems too complicated for me. I mean creating wrappers, virtual cameras and so on. I'm looking for just two methods - to open video and to add frame to the video.

Comment: I understand. Standard API has no offering for this. Then again what you refer to as "some codec" is in fact somewhat more complicated both technically and in terms of licensing. It is understandable you are looking for a library that covers all this, and even regardless this is off-topic for SO, I have no third party product/library to suggest.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a library. The reason I suggested the service is because it handles streaming, converting to different formats, etc. (to the best of my understanding) -- essentially does a lot of the heavy lifting. I started looking at it for a potential future project of mine.